# LCD Viewing angle for 8 COM vs 4 COM

Tags: lcd, pins

I'm planning to make a custom LCD made. The LCD has 128 segments. Now, in order to drive it, I have two options :

- Use 4 COM + 32 pins
- Use 8 COM + 16 pins

The MCU which I'm looking at (STM8L052R8) has support for 4 COM x 28 (112) or 8 COM x 24 (192). Since I have 128 segments, If I choose this MCU, then I'll need to go for 8COM config (8x16 = 128).

Many vendors have flatly told me that the viewing would not be good, and given me advice that 4COM would be better to view. Since I've little idea what they mean, I need better understanding of why this is so. And how bad would this viewing angle be, apart from other issues which I dont know of if 8 COM is used.

My expectation is its okay if the LCD has to be viewed in a 45 degree range.

Comment: I don't understand what you you mean by "LCD made". Do you mean 32", LCD TV monitor, or  7" HDMI LCD monitor, or 640 x 480 64k color graphics display, or 16 char x 2 line LCD monochrome display, each character is 5 dots by 7 dots?  Do you have any particular LCD driver in mind, or do you hope to directly drive the LCD using STM8L0528? As I know the viewing angle is a characteristic of the hardware display, not programmable by software. I admit that I only know how to drive 640 x 480 graphics display and 20 char x 4 lines LCD display. I would be grateful if you can upgrade my LCD knowledge.

Comment: @tlfong01 It is clearly about segmented LCD.

Comment: @Chupacabras, thanks a lot for your guidance. I am a electronics hobbyist and have never heard about "***segmented LCD***". I must google to know more. Cheers.

Comment: @Chupacabras, do you mean those 7-segment character displays? The segment drivers I have been playing is called MAX7219. I used it to display 7 and 16 segments characters, and also scalable 8 x 8 dot matrix LED displays. They are dirt cheap and good for newbies to learn matrix displays. / to continue, ...

Comment: @Chupacabras (1) MAX7219 Lattice Modules 4-in-One Tube Digital Display Module 8x8 Common Cathode Single Chip Module US$1 - US$4
https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32907492270.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.a0a937d8vqMSfM&algo_pvid=a8094fe6-7096-42f2-bcd1-1f0a0aebade5&algo_expid=a8094fe6-7096-42f2-bcd1-1f0a0aebade5-24&btsid=0bb0623016031866260986321e39e1&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

(2) SPI MAX7219 Serially Interfaced, 8-Digit, LED Display Drivers - Maxim
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/display-power-control/MAX7219.html. / to continued, ..

Comment: @Chupacabras, There are many MAX7219 demo Arduino programs around. I found it easy to direct program in Rpi python. I think they are good for newbies to learn SPI. But I don't understand why the OP mentions 45 degree veiwing angle and 4COM and 8 COM. Perhaps I need to google harder.

Comment: @Chupacabras, I also played with LCD drivers, but they are tedious to program, using 4 or 8 GPIO pins  Fortunately now there are I2C interface LCD modules which are easy to interface.
(3) HD44780 LCD Driver - Hitachi
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller

(4) LCD Fundamentals and the LCD Driver Module of 8-Bit PIC Microcontrollers - App Notes AN658, MicroChip
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN658-LCD-Fundamentals-and-the-LCD-Driver-Module-of-8-Bit-PIC-MCUs-00000658C.pdf. Cheers.

Comment: Guys it's custom lcd glass display, like those in medical handheld devices. Tf display without Backlight.

Comment: And there would be 7 segment display and a few icons.

Comment: @Ouroboros, Ah I see, so let us narrow down it and use the handheld display used by the staff (doctors and nurses say) in a hospital or clinic. Looking at the big picture, it is the ***CIS (Clinical Information Systems)***. At the very top, there is the global big data database in the cloud, that can be assessed by a city say. At the city level there are city level and district level (18 districts) big data database. Then down to hospital and clinics, perhaps hundreds. Now let us zoom into a ward of a hospital with 200 medial staff, each has an ***iPad and/or iPhone***, to continue, ......

Comment: @tlfong01 you're not helping. I am not sure if you have any questions..

Comment: @Ouroboros, Well I am trying to help. I was once a freelance IT consultant in the feasibility study phase of a Clinical Info System of a big hospital of a South East Asia city. I had been watching how the NHS CIS in another Continent going up and down. In case you might wonder why I mention about iPad and iPhone. I did once argued with a med guy down very South, on why using Apple and not Android in CIS. But I have not touched CIS for a long while, so I might have talking foolish things and upset you.  My apologies. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 No need for apologies mate. Just let me know what issues I might encounter, when going for a custom display with 8 COM pins.

Comment: Ah, now I know what do you mean by 4 COM and 8 COM. I do remember that when I used Arduino to program Hitachi HD44780 LCD Controller, I had two choices, using 8 Arduino GPIO pins or 4 GPIO pins. Using 8 pins the refresh frame rate is high, 4 pins low. Now your LCD might have many more pixel to deal with than the 640 x 480 display I was playing. I remember I could import use a Chinese character ROM with I forgot how many 5 x 7 dot Chinese character patterns and display Chinese characters. There are also Japanese characters and English alphabets. / to continue, ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115378/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-ouroboros).

Comment: @tlfong01 I think you're going in wrong direction. The COM pins are to multiplex the clock to ensure running 128 segments is possible in less number of pins. If 4 COM pins are there, then 128/4 = 32 and if 8 COM, then 128/8=16 extra pins are needed.

Comment: You are right, I am using the wrong LCD river. Actually what driver are you using?

Comment: I'm planning to use MCU with LCD driver. I've mentioned in my details "STM8L052R8" as the MCU. Please read the entire description carefully